# Why don't images used in xibs show up in app wide searches

Tags: xcode, xib

I am in the process of going through a large project and removing unused image assets.  I had been using cmd+shift+f to perform a project wide search for given image names.  I'd assumed this was working until I realized that if I set an imageview to display an image in interface builder that image reference was not showing up in my search.

Why doesn't the app wide search look for a value within an xib file?

Below is an image in a sample project which recreates the issue.  I'm assigning img2 in the xib, but as you can see in the search results img2.png is not found.

[image: screenshot of project running, and loading img2.png into imageview2. This can be seen in the image property of the imageview]

Comment: It just does not do that - xibs are not evaluated within the Search Navigator functionality.

Comment: If an xib file is xml content why can't that be searched?

Comment: It can (e.g. using a commandline search using grep) - Xcode however does not do that. I can not give you any reasoning as I did not build Xcode.